# Why does my simple UDPServer only receive packets from UDPClient only when it runs first?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

My UDP client will continuously send "Hello Server!" every 2 seconds to the UDP server (who just echos the message but in uppercase). They will both print what they've received.

My problem is that I would always have to run the server first then the client. If I run the client then server, the server would not receive anything at all. I want the server to start any time he wants and still receive packets from the client. How can I do this?

**UDPClient:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPClient
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
      while(true) {
         DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
         InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
         byte[] sendData = new byte[100];
         byte[] receiveData = new byte[100];
         String sentence = "Hello Server!";
         sendData = sentence.getBytes();
         DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9876);
         clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
         DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
         clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
         String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
         System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
         clientSocket.close();
         Thread.sleep(2000);
      }

   }
}
```

**UDPServer:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPServer
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
      {
         DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[100];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[100];
            while(true)
               {
                  DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                  serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                  String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
                  System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
                  InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                  int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                  String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
                  sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
                  DatagramPacket sendPacket =
                  new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                  serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
               }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the client first it will get an exception `PortUnreachableException` and the client program will close, in order for that not to happen you have to catch the exception so the client keeps on running.

try:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPClient
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
      while(true) {
         try{
         DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
         InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
         byte[] sendData = new byte[100];
         byte[] receiveData = new byte[100];
         String sentence = "Hello Server!";
         sendData = sentence.getBytes();
         DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9876);
         clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
         DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
         clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
         String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
         System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
         clientSocket.close();
         }
         catch (PortUnreachableException pe)
         {
           System.out.println("COULDN'T CONNECT TO SERVER:" + pe.getMessage());
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
           System.out.println("COULDN'T CONNECT TO SERVER:" + ex.getMessage());
         }
         Thread.sleep(2000);
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this but I still get the same results. It's not even printing the catch for `PortUnreachableException`.

Comment: No output, it just sits there like before. Any luck on your machine?

Comment: Made a little fix, it runs fine now.

Comment: Not correct. It will only get a `PortUnreachableException` if it issued a `connect()` first, which it doesn't, in which case the send will fail silently.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the Client first, when it tries to send "Hello server!" for the first time, it'll result in `PortUnreachableException`. And so, nothing is sent to the server at all. Wrap the socket code in a try/catch and ignore the exception condition.

Comment: Is there any way I can modify it so that client can keep broadcasting "Hello Server!" and the server will receive it once it's run?

Comment: Is your client crashing with a stack trace?

Comment: @TimBender how do I find out if it is?

Comment: Um, when you run the program, there should be a console associated with it. Either the command prompt you used to call Java or within your IDE.

Comment: Another is to just wrap the socket code in a try/catch and ignore the exception condition. @Zander you should edit your answer...

Comment: @TimBender tried Euclides solution, not working unfortunately... any clues?

Comment: Not correct. It will only get a `PortUnreachableException` if it issued a `connect()` first, which it doesn't, in which case the send will fail silently. The suggestion to 'loop until the connection is established' is completely meaningless.

Comment: @meiryo EJP is right about not receiving an exception. I've added an answer which includes code that I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you don't run the server first the datagrams are just dropped into the bit bucket. The only mitigation is for the client to call connect() first, in which case he will get a `PortUnreachableException,` probably on the *next* send, telling him there is nobody home.

Comment: New to UDP stuff but isn't that how UDP works? It doesn't care if the message is guaranteed to be sent. Or is it just my implementation.

Comment: @meiryo That's what I said. The message is dropped silently, unless you connect(), in which case you can get the exception I mentioned on a subsequent send. This is not implementation-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now that it is morning I've had a look again. Indeed, no exceptions are being thrown. The actual problem is that when you start the client first, it is sitting and waiting for the server to respond. However, it will never receive a response from the server because the server was not started in time to receive the request.

```
     clientSocket.send(sendPacket); //send message which will not be received
     clientSocket.receive(receivePacket); //wait forever for a response to a request that was never heard
```

A working solution is to have the client be multithreaded. One thread will be responsible for sending out requests while the other thread will be responsible for receiving incoming responses. Here is a hackish solution:

```
class UDPClient {
   public static void main(final String args[]) throws Exception {
      final InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
      new Thread() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            while (true) {
               DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;
               try {
                  clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                  byte[] sendData = new byte[100];
                  final String sentence = "Hello Server!";
                  sendData = sentence.getBytes();
                  final DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9876);
                  clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
                  Thread.sleep(2000);
               } catch (final Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               } finally {
                  clientSocket.close();
               }
            }
         }
      }.start();
      new Thread() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;
            try {
               clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            } catch (final SocketException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (true) {
               try {
                  final byte[] receiveData = new byte[100];
                  final DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                  clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                  final String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                  System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
               } catch (final Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
         }
      }.start();
   }

}
```